# How do I get just the non-static (or just the static) fields or methods of a class, via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I see

```
MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()
MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()
```

but how do I get just the non-static or just the static members?

Comment: FYI, it was the first result on Google for "java static field reflection".

Comment: @Michael - Woops. When I searched with "non-static" instead of "static" and including "getDeclaredMethods", I got totally different results about invoking non-static methods. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Modifier#isStatic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isStatic-int-) for that, for example:

```
Field[] fields = Main.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
    if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
}
```

This will print `b` if `Main` is:

```
public class Main {

    public String a;
    public static String b;


}
```